# can we identify the id of a button in mvc on httppost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a view which has two submit buttons(save&close,save&new).

```
 <span>
    <input type="button" value="Save&New" name="Save&New" id="SaveNew" />
    </span>
    <span>
    <input type="button" value="Save&Close" name="Save&Close" id="SaveClose" />
    </span>
    <span>
```

When i hit any one of these buttons,the model data goes to controller and hits a post action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Company(MyProject.Models.Company company)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

now my company object has complete model data(such as company.phonenumber,company.state etc etc).
Now i want to identify the id of the button(either save&new or save&close) user clicked.
Both buttons click leads to same ActionResult(Company) and i just want to identify from which button click the request came.
Cannot use @Html.ActionLink instead of input type =submit.
Need to know the Id with out using Jquery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give your buttons the same name:

```
<button type="submit" name="btn" value="save_new" id="SaveNew">Save&amp;New</button>
<button type="submit" name="btn" value="save_close" id="SaveClose">Save&amp;Close</button>
```

and then your controller action could take this `btn` string parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Company(MyProject.Models.Company company, string btn)
{
    if (btn == "save_new")
    {
        // the form was submitted using the Save&New button
    }
    else if (btn == "save_close")
    {
        // the form was submitted using the Save&Close button
    }
    else
    {
        // the form was submitted using javascript or the user simply
        // pressed the Enter key while being inside some of the input fields
    }

    return View();
}
```

Also notice that I have used `submit` buttons (`type="submit"`) whereas in your example you have used simple buttons (`type="button"`) which do not allow for submitting an html form.

Comment: the same worked with <input type="submit" name="btn" value="SaveNew" id="SaveNew" />

Comment: Yes, but this way you rely on the text of the button: `value="SaveNew"`. In my example you could have a specific value for the button which you will use for checking in your controller action and an entirely different user friendly label for the button.